# cordova installing error on windows

Tags: cordova

C:>npm install -g cordova
(node:5216) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are
 using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\bisho melek\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"

npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\bisho melek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node
_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\bisho melek\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\bish
o melek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_m
odules'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\b
isho melek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\nod
e_modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -4094,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\Users\bisho melek\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\bisho melek\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"

npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! path C:\npm-debug.log.5648d9f247f9a3808bd92cdb034ab28f
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\npm-debug.log.5648d9f24
7f9a3808bd92cdb034ab28f'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\npm-debug.log.5648d9
f247f9a3808bd92cdb034ab28f'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\npm-debug.log.5648d9f247f9a3808bd92cdb034ab28f' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log

Comment: Please format your question, because it's very hard to read.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this issue ? Have you tried to launch this command on an adminstrator command line ?